Is this the right way of creating Multi User Access for Django?
I actually confused right now on how to implement the Multi-User Access with Django v5.3. I am actually new in this backend and I would like to create a login where users can redirect to specific dashboards based on their accesslevel type (Providers,Admin,Validator,Students).
Here is the app that I made so far... I have no views yet because I am not confident enough to my models.py but I hope this is good enough.
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.




class User(AbstractUser):
    
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_validator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_provider = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.FileField
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    gwa = models.FloatField(max_length=100)
    graduated_at = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    year = models.DateField()


class Validators(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.FileField
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   
    
class Provider(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    company_website = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    avatar = models.FileField
    
    
class Admin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.FileField(upload_to='avatars')
    
    





This is really a question of database design, and as a rule it depends heavily upon your application's requirements.
That said, given the assumption that you want to distinguish different user types separately from the User() model, one way to approach this is with a Profile model (or something similar).
Having all these different model classes as hard-coded user types strikes me as inflexible and overly complex.  Here's a sample approach:
class User(AbstractUser):

    is_student   = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_validator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_provider  = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin     = models.BooleanField(default=False)


USER_TYPES = [ 
     ('', ' - '),
     ('student', 'Student'),
     ('validator', 'Validator'),
     ('provider', 'Provider'),
     ('admin', 'Administrator'),
     ]


class Profile(models.Model):
    user        = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name='user_profile')
    user_type   = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=USER_TYPE, default=USER_TYPE[0][0], blank=True, null=True)
    avatar      = models.FileField()
    address     = models.CharField()
    # Add all other required fields here as needed


Very oversimplified example here, but the point is that your users and user types remain abstract and flexible implementing a Profile() model.  You can query against it filtering for user_type.
In some production applications I have implemented, the Profile() object is generated automatically upon user login, or account creation, and awaits further data.  Your requirements may vary.
An even better approach to the user_type field would be a foreign key to a UserType(models.Model) table where user types are tracked as objects, with specific IDs.
As far as what you mean by multi-user "access" you may need to explain further.

Thank you sir, I found out that Django is too way complicated for me as this time.
